# Crystal report using SQL Server data, combining two tables

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, crystal-reports

Hi good people at StackOverFlow,

This morning I have found myself having a few issues with getting the correct results when attempting to view reports in my C# application using Crystal Reporting.

I'm attempting to build reports based on a user's entry when selecting an 'Employee Number' from a drop-down list within my application, so far Iv'e got the drop-down list populated with the database column records but I just cannot find a way to build a report when users select an option.

Please could someone give me an insight on how this is done or even direct me into the right place to learn how to perform such an action, I'm here to learn and would rather find my way around this issue as a means to gain knowledge rather than just simply asking for a user to fix my problem...

Thanks people!

Answer (score 0):

Create your report in design with your whole table to be displayed. Then you can either create a parameter in crystal reports to filter the value by your selected value from combo box or you can set your query while loading the report with the Filtered query.
eg:

```
 string query = String.Concat("Select * from wharever where something like ",yourcombobox.text);
```

Then set this query as the query to produce the report.